# Is 二千〇二十 - 八月 - 二十九 correct?

Tags: translation, time

I’ve got this but I don't know if it’s set out right or even if it’s the correct translation.

> 二千〇二十 - 八月 -  二十九

Could anyone help please?

Answer (score 3):

I am sorry to tell you. No, the Year is in the wrong format.

In Chinese, Years are read in the formate of 4-digits. It should be 二零二零年 八月 二十九日.

The only exceptions are 2000"两千年", 2001"两千零一年" ~ 2009"两千零九年". These are not as official as "二零零零年", "二零零一年" ~ "二零零九年". The 4-digits format is always preferred.

"日" can be omitted, but usually not. But "年" is rarely omitted.

二〇二〇年 is also correct but 〇 is semi-Chinese. I mean it is officially correct, but not appealing. 二零二零年 is more often used.

Finally, the suggested translation is:

#### 二零二零年 八月 二十九日

Comment: I often wonder why 〇 is rarely used, despite it is the official character for 0(beside it could be hard to write correctly), where 零 should be used as the capital letter for it.

Comment: The simple reason is 〇 looks ugly. It does not fit into any font of Chinese. Chinese printings care a lot about calligraphy. Imagine that you have a slogan printed big. Every other character is in nice 楷体 that looks like 颜真卿's artwork but have a simple geometric circle in the middle. It will be very awkward. 零 will always be correct, but 〇 can only be used in years.

Answer (score 1):

二千〇二十 - 八月 - 二十九 is definitely wrong. It seems that it is generated by computer.

People either write 二〇二〇年八月二十九日 or 二零二零年八月二十九日. Note that there is no space after 年 and 月.

Alternatively, 二十九 might be replaced with 廿九 and 日 might be replaced with 號.

A hundred years ago, 2020 would be written as 二千零二十年. 二千零二十年八月二十九日 is also correct but rarely used nowadays. It makes writing like historical document.

Although some numbers like 二千〇二十 did exist in the history, but we seldom write like this. We usually write 二千零二十. The 零 here means a smaller number follows, not zero.

Usually writing digits use 〇 like 一九〇三 and otherwise 零 like 一千九百零三. But some people would refrain from writing 〇 and 一九零三 is also common. 〇 looks like something foreign. Also 〇 might be very hard to type in some input methods. And also, 〇 is a placement holder symbol for missing or hidden characters.

Believe it or not. 〇 came to ancient China with Buddhism. It is nothing new.

Answer (score 0):

Objection. 二〇二〇年八月二十九日 is the only correct expression for a date written in Chinese characters.
《出版物上数字用法》(*Usage of Numbers in Publication*, GB/T15835-2011) states that if zero is used for numbering, it should be written as 〇.

Comment: Actually, it is only mainland Chinese standard that requires to use 〇 for the independent digit 0.